# Как лучше реализовать такой демон?

Tags: c#, http, java, c++

Хочу написать демон, чтобы он подключался к базе данных и держал соединение. Теперь с веб странички подключаемся к демону, обменивается данными через соединение, отключаемся... Но соединение с базой продолжаем держать...

Посоветуйте, как лучше реализовать такой демон?
Помогите, плиз, с названием...

Comment: Можно написать на чем угодно. К примеру, на перле будет пару десятков строк + строки для обработки различных входных данных. (при этом будет использоваться http/rest для клиентов).

Comment: Эм, а сам сервер базы данных не является чем-то аналогичным?

Comment: наверное, перл не вариант, не написал на нём ни одной строчки) ...
а сам сервер? а как не потерять соединение с ним?

Comment: @sitev_ru, какую именно проблему вы решаете? Какая разница сайту, запрашивает он напрямую сервер или демон? Какая разница серверу, подключается к нему сайт или демон?

Comment: так поставлена задача, что нужно некоторое продолжительно время хранить данные в памяти сервера, чтобы PL/SQL общался с переменными и они не обнулялись... например, нажимаем на сайте кнопку 1 - присваиваем переменной в PL/SQL значение 1, нажимаем 2 - присваиваем 2... с таблицами не общаемся)

Comment: @sitev_ru, что мешает хранить это значение прямо в базе данных? Разработка демона **значительно** дороже любых костылей и подъема любых сервисов на сервере.

Comment: Разработка демона значительно дороже, а что делать??? Так поставлена задача...

Comment: @sitev_ru ставлю традиционные пять баксов, что задача не подразумевает написание демона. Почему это значение нельзя хранить прямо в БД?

Comment: Ещё как можно хранить, но не нужно, потому что ТАК ПОСТАВЛЕНА ЗАДАЧА! )))

Comment: Название: C# WCF :)

Comment: что то мне кажется, что memcache, возможно плюс redis, решат все вопросы @sitev_ru .

Comment: Смотрите в сторону fastcgi. Библиотеки есть под все популярные ЯП.

Comment: @sitev_ru, а разве переменные в PL/SQL сохраняют свои значения между вызовами программы (кроме как в таблицах базы, используя обращения к СУБД, откуда и могут быть снова прочитаны)?

--

Про масштаб программы, реализующей PL/SQL (очевидно с какими-то, специфичными для proxy  расширениями) я даже и не говорю.

Comment: @sitev_ru, а эта ПОСТАВЛЕННАЯ ЗАДАЧА учебная или для серьезного продакшена?

Если учебная, и нужно с веб-странички что-то дергать и состояние в памяти держать, я бы предложил получать удовольствие с любым динамическим языком и легковесным веб-сервером. Node.js, python, ruby, perl, clojure, groovy - на ваш вкус.

Например на ruby/sinatra минимальный сервер, хранящий в памяти количество вызовов страницы:

    require 'sinatra'

    set :counter, 0

    get '/' do
      settings.counter = settings.counter + 1
      "counter value: #{settings.counter}"
    end